# How should substitution be noted?

Tags: notation

In my thesis, I want to describe replacing equality constraints with inequalities in a constrained optimization problem. But I'm not sure how it should be mathematically noted. This is my current notation:

$$
h_i(x)=0 \rightarrow |h_i(x)|<\varepsilon_i, i=1,2, ... ,p \\
\therefore |h_i(x)|-\varepsilon_i<0 \rightarrow h'_i(x)<0
$$

I used "$\rightarrow$" twice with two different meanings. In first line I am assuming that two sides of arrow are equivalent and in second line I defined a new function ($h'(x)$). I know that the right-arrow is used for [implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional), which is totally irrelevant here, but what is the correct notation?

Comment: This is a matter of opinion, but I generally prefer to use words unless notation is really going to make things easier to understand.  So, in this case, it might make sense to say some like "Replace the equalities $h_i(x)=0$ with the inequalities $|h_i(x)| < \varepsilon_i$."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A\rightarrow B$ is conventional for generative grammars and rewrite systems, $[A/B]$ for logical calculi. But please use $\text{replace }A\text{ with }B$ if your audience isn't an expert in such systems and $\Rightarrow$ for implication to avoid overloading $\rightarrow$.

Edit: Making some educated guesses on what you mean, I would probably write what you wrote as something like

> Consider the relaxation of Equation [ref. number of eq. block for program] such that, for each $i$ in $\{1,2,\ldots,p\}$, the equality constraint
>   $$h_i(x)=0$$
>   is replaced by an inequality
>   $$\lvert h_i(x)\rvert<\varepsilon_i$$
>   for some positive real $\varepsilon_i$.
>   Then by defining auxiliary functions
>   $$\begin{align}k_i&\colon X\to\mathbb{R}& k_i(x)&\stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \lvert h_i(x)\rvert-\varepsilon_i& (i&\in\{1,2,\ldots,p\})\end{align}$$
>   the new constraints may be simplified to the standard form
>   $$\begin{align}k_i(x)&<0&(i&\in\{1,2,\ldots,p\})\text{.}\end{align}$$

In particular, I'd avoid using a prime to denote a new function (too easily confused with a derivative), a "$\rightarrow$" between two propositions to define a function with restricted domain and range (it's almost certain to be read as implication), and shorthand proof symbols like "$\therefore$" (useful when drafting proofs, but potentially disruptive in the final prose).

Comment: Thanks Dave. Do you recommend `replace A with B` notation for both usages? Is this OK if I write: $replace h_i(x)=0 with |h_i(x)|<\epsilon_i, i=1,2, ... ,p$ and $replace |h_i(x)|-\epsilon_i<0 with h'_i(x)<0$?

Comment: I've added an example.